# Show user group in CP user listing?

Tags: control-panel, user-groups

I want to scan my user list to see if anyone *hasn't* been assigned to a group.

Is there a way to show user groups as a column at `admin/users`?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way baked in to Craft - probably something to do with the fact that users can be in multiple groups. Although I totally agree it would be useful, like at least listing the first group they're in, like the Entries view does with Categories.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can get a list of users who haven't been assigned groups through the front-end:

```
{% set users = craft.users.group(['not', 'foo', 'bar']) %}

{% if users|length %}
    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li>{{ user.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Just replace `foo` and `bar` with your group handles, and add more if necessary.